# java cyclic reference and garbage collections

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, cyclic-reference

Let's consider the following 2 cyclic referencing examples:

**Straight forward cyclic referencing**

```
class A {        
    B b;        
}

class B {
    A a;
}
```

**[WeakReferenceing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html)**

```
class A {
    B b;
}

class B {
    WeakReference<A> aRef;
}
```

The following [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427363/garbage-collection-behavior-with-isolated-cyclic-references) answered by [@Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/427370/101715) makes clear that the straight forward example will also be garbage collected as long as no "GC walk" from a known root exists to the cycle.

My question is as follows:

Is there any reason performance or otherwise to use or not to use the idiom represented in example 2 - the one employing a WeakReference?

Comment: I would not make the code more complicated or use more concepts than it needs to, instead of saying "Why not?" ask yourself "Is there a good reason I need to do this?"

Comment: @PeterLawrey that is exactly my question: "Is there any good reason...?" My point had been to understand if I am missing something concerning cycles, weakreferences & GCs. I sure did not intend to use example #2 blindly and in all situations. I had wanted to know if there is a situation in which it is preferable, or if none exists...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any reason performance or otherwise to use or not to use the idiom represented in example 2

The Java `Reference` types have a couple of performance implications:

- They use more space than regular references.
- They are significantly more work for the garbage collector than ordinary references.
- I also believe that they can cause the collection of objects to be delayed by one or more GC cycles ... depending on the GC implementation.

In addition the application has to deal with the possibility that a `WeakReference` may be broken

By contrast, there are no performance or space overheads for normal cyclic references as you use them in your first example.

In summary, your weak reference idiom reduces performance and increases program complexity ... with no tangible benefits that I can see.

---

<sup>My guess is that this Question derives from the *mistaken* notion that cyclic references are more expensive than non-cyclic references in Java ... or that they are somehow problematic.  (What other logical reason would cause one to propose an "idiom" like this?) In fact, this is not the case.  Java garbage collectors don't suffer from the problems of reference counting; e.g. C++ "smart pointers".  Cyclic references are handled correctly (i.e. without leaking memory) and efficiently in Java.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you do not know when GC will clear the weakreference objects.

It may be cleared just as you declare it! GC is very eager to collect it.

Or you can have root reference to the weakreference object to prevent it from the garbage collection.

Or check its status through RegisteredQueue.

It's like finalize method. You do not know when GC will execute this method.

Sources:

http://pawlan.com/monica/articles/refobjs/
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html

Comment: Presumably you mean "finalize", not "finally", in the last sentence.