# Garbage Collection at a BinaryTree

Tags: java, garbage-collection

```
class Node<E> {
E element;
Node<E> left;
Node<E> right;
...

Node<E> root;
//...
Node<E> a;
Node<E> b; // = a.left
Node<E> c; // = b.left
```

`Node a` the one which is in connection with the `root` of the tree.

I would like to remove `b` from `root->...->a->b->c` chain to get `root->...a->c`

**My question:**

If i set `a.left` reference to `c`, will `b` get garbage collected, or i must also set `b.left` reference to `null`?

I know an object is collected if no reference **to** it, but what if there is reference **from** it? I suppose it does not count, but i would like to be sure about it.

Comment: You are correct. An object is eligible for collection if there is no reference to it. Period.

Comment: You could see this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506303/question-about-garbage-collection-in-java?rq=1.  The first anwer by Jon Skeet states "garbage collects everything that it hasn't deemed to be live.".

Comment: You can always build a small example using [`PhantimReference`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html) to see that the reference to `b` is really garbage-collected.