# [Java]Interfaces and memory leaks

Tags: java, memory-leaks, interface

I have doubt about interfaces and memory leaks, considering the block of code below, could it bring to a memory leak?
If so what's the best solution or alternative?

```
public class MyClass {
    public interface MyClassListener{
         doStuff();
    }

    public doSomething(){}
}

public class OtherClass {

    private List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
    private boolean doingStuff = false;

    public void setListener(MyClassListener list) { //Sets the listener}

    public MyClass.MyClassListener listener = new MyClass.MyClassListener() {
        public void doStuff(){ doingStuff = true; }
    }

    public void addMyClass(MyClass obj) {
        obj.setListener(listener);
        list.add(obj);
    }

    public void doSomethingInMyClass(int index) {
        ....update some stuff....
        list.get(index).doSomething();
    }
}
```

i know i could declare the variable `listener` as `static` so it wont hold a reference to `OtherClass` and assign that reference to a `WeakReference` but am i going to a memory leak anyway?
Since the reference will hold a reference to an object containing a list which contains my object. It is like a chain.

**Update**

I updated my question, as you can see `MyClass` has a method called `doSomething()`, instead `OtherClass` has a method called `doSomethingInMyClass` which calls the `doSomething` method but updates some parameters.
What i want is to avoid to use `doSomethingInMyClass` and get notified of the changes anyway.

Comment: This is what's called an island of self-referencing objects. Java's garbage collection is able to remove those when the last reference from outside the island is gone.

Comment: It means it will remove the `OtherClass` object when the list will be empty?

Comment: Yes. Java Garbage Collection starts with the _active threads'_ local variables, plus the _static_  members of all loaded classes. Those are the first-level living objects. Then GC recursively marks all objects that are referred from these living objects. The rest (unreferences objects) are removed from the heap after the GC.

Comment: Have a look at this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407855/how-does-java-garbage-collector-handle-self-reference

Comment: Please see my update, i don't want to know how it is garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of your situation:

```
interface I { }

class A {
    List<I> list = new ArrayList<>();
    void add(I item) { list.add(item); }
}

class B {
    A other;
    void setA(A a) {
        final B self = this;
        a.add(new I() { B owner = self; });
        other = a;
    }
}

[...]

public static void main (String[] args)
{                   // 1
    A a = new A();  // 2
    B b = new B();  // 3
    b.setA(a);      // 4
}                   // 5
```

At the start of the scope in `main` the set of references is empty in (1). `a` and `b` are set to reference each other in (4). Then the references to `a` and `b` are removed at the end of the scope in (5). The result is an island of self-referencing objects.

You can visualise the set of (non-`null`) references as follows:

1. `{}`
2. `{a, a.list}`
3. `{a, a.list, b}`
4. `{a, a.list, a.list[0], a.list[0].owner, b, b.other}`
5. `{a.list, a.list[0], a.list[0].owner, b.other}`

In the end you have a reference to a list in `a`, it contains one or multiple references to the internal `I` in `B` which contains a reference to its owner `b`, wich contains a reference to `a`. When the garbage collector adds up the reference counts per object from this list it can remove them all if those counts are equal to the actual reference counts (i.e. the list is completely self-referential).